# What is Ubuntu SSO?

Tags: single-sign-on

At [login.ubuntu.com](https://login.ubuntu.com/) it says Ubuntu Single Sign On.
What are its uses?
How is it useful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

login.ubuntu.com is a service used by various Ubuntu websites that allow you to use a single account for login instead of creating a separate account for each.

Comment: It's not only useful for websites but for any cloud service. It's you Ubuntu One login and you can even set up your own machine to log in using it.

Comment: It is true that login.ubuntu.com does use OpenID, but as far as i know there are no pam modules allowing OpenID logins.